# Merging branch which contains revert commit to master overriding changes in master

Tags: git, merge

We created a branch (release) from master (mainline). After some commits by mistake we take the pull of mainline into release and push it. On realising this we revert the merged push. Now when we are merging release back to mainline then our changes in mainline are getting overridden.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you merging `release` onto `master`?

Anyway if you really want to do that you could either `revert` the revert, or delete the revert with `git reset --hard HEAD~`, then `git push -f origin`.

Comment: Thanks, we revert the revert from mainline and now it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of merging release back to master branch , use git cherry-pick to sync required commits.

Comment: This should also work but there were many commits after the reverted commit so cherry-picking commits will be hard.

Comment: as you had mentioned "some commits" in the question, I had suggested cherry-pick which is feasible for few commits.

good to see that you fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the revert you did created commit `R`, after merging `release` into `master` do the following: `git revert R` (while on `master`). This should leave both branches in the correct state.